# Is there any way to create class instances with dynamically-created public members?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I need to create a bunch of table columns and corresponding models for them.

Example 1:

```
object MyTable: IdTable<UUID>("my_table") {
    override val id = uuid("id").autoGenerate().entityId()

    val myField = date("my_field")
    val myAnotherField = date("my_another_field");
    // more fields ...

}

open class MyModel(id: EntityID<UUID>) : UUIDEntity(id) {
    companion object : UUIDEntityClass<MyModel>(MyTable) {
        fun doStuff(): MyModel {
            // shared functionality goes here.
        }
    }

    var myField by MyTable.myField
    var myAnotherField by MyTable.myAnotherField
    // more fields ...
}
```

Example 2:

```
object MyTable2: IdTable<UUID>("my_table") {
    override val id = uuid("id").autoGenerate().entityId()

    val myField2 = date("my_field_2")
    val myAnotherField2 = date("my_another_field_2");
    // more fields ...
}

open class MyModel2(id: EntityID<UUID>) : UUIDEntity(id) {
    companion object : UUIDEntityClass<MyModel>(MyTable2) {
        fun doStuff(): MyModel {
            // shared functionality goes here.
        }
    }

    var myField2 by MyTable2.myField2
    var myAnotherField2 by MyTable2.myAnotherField2
    // more fields ...
}
```

I'd like to avoid the repetitive task of mapping table members to model members, so my goal is to create a factory class that produces instances based on the `Map` it was provided with:

```
class Factory(val fields: Fields, val tableName: String) {
    fun getTable() {
        // TODO
    }
    fun getModel() {
        // TODO
    }
}

val fields: Fields = mapOf(
    "myField" to date("my_field"),
    "myAnotherField" to date("my_another_field"),
    // more fields ...
)

val instances = Factory(fields, "my_table")
```

I think I hit the wall because the deeper I dig, the more I feel it's impossible with Kotlin. Reflections seem to be a solution, but I'm unsure if it's a good idea because I would like my code to be type-safe.

I'm coming from TypeScript so I was hoping to be able to take advantage of generics and union types, but Kotlin generics are not that sophisticated.

Comment: At first glance I think you want to get type safe features for dynamic code. You can theoretically write a "class" by using e.g. a HashMap for entity representation, then you would access entities via map accessors. Or you can have type safety and define the classes (which are then available at compile time, which seems to be what you want), but then you have to write them. Alternatively you can generate the model based on a simplified definition language. Either way, something will have to give...

Comment: Maybe look at a compiler plugin that read your table input and spit out a type-safe model class: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-why-ksp.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid that what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible with Kotlin language, now I'm thinking about code generation, e.g. KotlinPoet https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/

Comment: It depends on how generic is your models. If you can create some kind of an interface, then you can try to workaround this, but all specific model fields/methods will not be available without an explicit cast.